# Is element $5 + 2i$ irreducible in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring

I want to prove that $5 + 2i$ is an irreducible in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. I was wondering how to do so without the use of the norm defined on this ring.

Let's suppose that it is reducible, i.e. $5 + 2i = (a + bi)(c + di)$ for some $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a + bi, c + di$ are not units. Thus

$$\begin{cases} 5 = ac - bd, \\ 2 = ad + bc.\end{cases}$$

How can I prove now that this system of equation does not have an integer solution?

**EDIT**

Extracting $c$ from the first equation, I get $c = \frac{5 + bd}{a}$, which substituted to the second one gives me $2a - 5b = d(a^2 + b^2)$ and therefore $d$ divides both $2a$ and $5b$. If $d \neq 1$, we've got $d |a$ and $d|b$, so the element $a + bi$ is invertible, which is contrary to the hypothesis?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you do not wish to use the norm on the ring?

Comment: **Use the norm**. But if you really don't want to, prove that $\Bbb Z[i]/(5+2i)\cong\Bbb Z/(29)$, carefully avoiding saying the word "norm".

Comment: @Student it hasn't been introduced in my classes and I only found out about it when researching this problem

Comment: Unfortunately from $2a - 5b = d(a^2 + b^2)$ you cannot conclude that $d$ divides both $2a$ and $5b$. It could also divide neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $5+2i = (a+ib)(c+id) = (ac - bd) + i(ad + bc)$.

Notice that

$$(a-ib)(c-id) = (ac - bd) - i(ad + bc) = 5-2i$$

Multiply these two equalities:

$$29 = 5^2 + 2^2 = (5+2i)(5-2i) = (a+ib)(c+id)(a-ib)(c-id) = (a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$$

Since $29$ is prime, this implies $a^2+b^2 = 1$ or $c^2+d^2 = 1$. In the first case we have

$$(a+ib)(a-ib) = a^2 + b^2 = 1 \implies (a+ib)^{-1} = a-ib$$

and in the second case we have

$$(c+id)(c-id) = c^2 + d^2 = 1 \implies (c+id)^{-1} = c-id$$

Hence, one of $a+ib$ and $c + id$ is invertible.

Therefore, $5+2i$ is irreducible.

Comment: This argument uses the norm without mentioning it, contrary to what the OP wishes.

Comment: @lhf True. However, I understood that the OP didn't wish to use the norm because it wasn't introduced in his class, not because it wasn't allowed. Therefore I provided an elementary argument which doesn't explicitly mention the norm or implicitly uses some of its properties such as $N(xy) =N(x)N(y)$ and $N(x) = 1 \iff x$ invertible.